# Nginx redirect the POST request from https to http

Tags: nginx

We are trying to develop an e-commerce feature where people can pay online and we have providers for that. We just implemented SSL however, one of our providers has an insecure URL that we send data to. So when we try to transact to them, the security warning will pop-up. Our request or data will come from our javascript front-end to our back-end then back-end will render form data on it's template and send a `form POST request` to our provider. The solution that I think of is to just pass that POST request to my http like from `https://www.example.com/payment` to `http://www.example.com`

Any other suggestions besides my idea is welcome

Answer (score 0):

I know now the answer! just use `return 307 http://example.com/payment/` like

```
location ^~ /payment/ {
    return 307 http://example.com/payment/
}
```